# Mac Mail Rule does not work

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail, email-filter

I've created an On My Mac mailbox.

Then I created an if-any rule: From is equal to [some@email.address], which performs Move Message to my newly created mailbox.

When done creating the rule, I clicked Apply, but **no messages appear in the new mailbox**.  As suggested by some, I've restarted Mail and recreated the rule, but does not help.

I'm 100% sure the email address I typed is correct and that I have multiple messages from that address. (When I create a Smart Mailbox with an identical From-is-equal, many messages appear.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? It's not clear.

Comment: @piko Apologies, I've added the problem now.